Issues using ODBC in C - sqlState returns IM008 (possible issues with connection string?)
I am having issues with the following implementation in C. (Of course I have obscured the sensitive info in the connection string).
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    SQLHENV hEnv;
    SQLHDBC hDbc;
    SQLRETURN ret; /* ODBC API return status */

    SQLCHAR* connStr = (SQLCHAR*)"DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; SERVER={tcp:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxxx}; UID=****; PWD=*****; DATABASE={SDC};\0";

    printf("%s\n", connStr);


    // Allocate an environment handle
    ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hEnv);
    if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        printf("Error allocating environment handle\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Set the ODBC version environment attribute
    ret = SQLSetEnvAttr(hEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        printf("Error setting environment attribute\n");
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
        return -1;
    }

    // Allocate a connection handle
    ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hEnv, &hDbc);
    if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        printf("Error allocating connection handle\n");
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
        return -1;
    }

    // Set login timeout to 5 seconds
    SQLSetConnectAttr(hDbc, SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)5, 0);

    // Connect to the SQL Server
    ret = SQLDriverConnect(hDbc, NULL, connStr, SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);

    if (ret == SQL_ERROR) {
        SQLCHAR sqlState[12] = { 0 };  // 5 characters + null terminator
        SQLINTEGER nativeError;
        SQLCHAR messageText[2048] = { 0 };  // Message buffer
        SQLSMALLINT messageLength;

        // Fetch diagnostic information
        ret = SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc, 1, sqlState, &nativeError, messageText, sizeof(messageText), &messageLength);

        // Null-terminate the message if it exceeds the buffer size
        if (messageLength > sizeof(messageText) - 1) {
            messageText[sizeof(messageText) - 1] = '\0';
        }

        printf("SQLSTATE: %s\n", sqlState);
        printf("Native Error Code: %d\n", nativeError);
        printf("Message: %s\n", messageText);
    }
    else if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        printf("Connection successful with info!\n");
    }
    else if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Connection successful!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Error connecting to the database\n");
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
        return -1;
    }

    // Close the connection and free handles
    SQLDisconnect(hDbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv); 

    return 0;
}


Working Python implementation:
import pyodbc as sql
import pandas as pd
import sys
import warnings
from time import (strftime, strptime)


server = 'tcp:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxxx'
db = 'SDC'

string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; SERVER={"+server+"}; UID=****; PWD=*****; DATABASE={"+db+"}; "

print(string)

try:
    db = sql.connect(string)
    print('It worked!')
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
    



It returns a Dialog failed message text and sqlState IM008. From what I see online it might be an error with the login credentials. However the string is exactly formatted as in a working Python implementation (below the C code). Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong? The printf statement shows the string exactly as I want it.

unrelated? your connection string ends with two '\0's: one literal in source code and another implied and automatically inserted by C itself. The Python string has a final space not present in the C string.

Indeed, I added it in a second moment to see if the issue was the absence of a null terminator. Outcome doesn't change.

The  tag is for ANSI/ISO SQL language related questions.

Maybe you need (SQLCHAR*)L"DRIVER={ODBC Dr..." Note the L to make it a "wide-char" string

So just add the L after casting the string?

No, you start with a wide-string wchar step1[] = L"DRIVER..."; and cast that wide-string for the connection (SQLCHAR* connStr = (SQLCHAR*)step1;). Remember to #include <wchar.h> (if it isn't already part of <windows.h>)

DATABASE={SDC} is this really correct for C? It doesn't do string interpolations me thinks

@siggemannen SDC is a string literal in OP's Python snippet

Hmm true, but don't think one is supposed to pass {} in connection strings in any language.

@pmg changing to wchar and casting worked! now the only issue I keep having is that visual studio keeps flagging sqlState and messageText as overflowing and the stack being damaged around sqlState. I have tried increasing the buffer but it doesn't change, should I worry about this?

@siggemannen the curly parenthesis are needed also in the python snippet, anyways now the connection string works

when I debug messageText I see a null terminator after every single character, and once the message stops it contains | until the buffer is full. I find this bevavior quite concerning....?

Can it be that also messageText is not in the correct type?

That's "wide-string" stuff. You're stuck with it, it's part of the inner workings of Windows. (Almost) all your char arrays need to become wchar, you need wprintf() and (probably) some other changes to be fully conformant. BTW: I think Python does all the wide-string stuff behind the scenes, automatically.

@pmg thank you so much for the detailed help, indeed I am not a native windows developer

Me neither. Good luck, have fun!

As correctly pointed out in the comments by @pmg the issue was that I did not use wchar (windows wide strings) in my code.
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
    SQLHENV hEnv;
    SQLHDBC hDbc;
    SQLRETURN ret; /* ODBC API return status */

    wchar_t connStr[] = L"DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; SERVER={tcp:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxxx}; UID=****; PWD=*****; DATABASE={SDC};";

    // Allocate an environment handle
    ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hEnv);
    if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        wprintf(L"Error allocating environment handle\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Set the ODBC version environment attribute
    ret = SQLSetEnvAttr(hEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        wprintf(L"Error setting environment attribute\n");
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
        return -1;
    }

    // Allocate a connection handle
    ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hEnv, &hDbc);
    if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        wprintf(L"Error allocating connection handle\n");
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
        return -1;
    }

    // Set login timeout to 5 seconds
    SQLSetConnectAttr(hDbc, SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)5, 0);

    // Connect to the SQL Server
    ret = SQLDriverConnectW(hDbc, NULL, connStr, SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);

    if (ret == SQL_ERROR || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        SQLWCHAR sqlState[6] = { 0 };  // 5 characters + null terminator
        SQLINTEGER nativeError;
        SQLWCHAR messageText[512] = { 0 };  // Message buffer
        SQLSMALLINT messageLength;
        int i = 1;

        // Fetch diagnostic information
        while (SQLGetDiagRecW(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc, i, sqlState, &nativeError, messageText, sizeof(messageText) / sizeof(SQLWCHAR), &messageLength) != SQL_NO_DATA) {
            // Null-terminate the message if it exceeds the buffer size
            if (messageLength > sizeof(messageText) / sizeof(SQLWCHAR) - 1) {
                messageText[sizeof(messageText) / sizeof(SQLWCHAR) - 1] = L'\0';
            }

            wprintf(L"SQLSTATE: %ls\n", sqlState);
            wprintf(L"Native Error Code: %d\n", nativeError);
            wprintf(L"Message: %ls\n", messageText);
            i++;
        }
    }

    if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        wprintf(L"Connection successful with info!\n");
    }
    else if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS) {
        wprintf(L"Connection successful!\n");
    }
    else {
        wprintf(L"Error connecting to the database\n");
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
        return -1;
    }

    // Close the connection and free handles
    SQLDisconnect(hDbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);

    return 0;
}


Don't add your solution to the question, add it here, in the answer.

You can approve it too @Fulvio :)

@siggemannen approve what, the answer? It says I can't approve my own answer until tomorrow...? Or you mean something else?

Yeah, your answer, ok, then you'll have to wait
